# How to scrape data from a website using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

[When I try to scrape the table data from the following link it displays nothing..](http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KM89.xml)  `

I write the following code but it gives nothing..I want the table data i.e last Update, weather, temperature from that link which is i given please help me..

```
url = "http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KM89.xml"

docs = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

puts docs.css("table")
```

Comment: I see your problem, there aren't much css selectors on that page. I suggest looking into XPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to that page, open your development tools and when you find the response of the request to KM89.xml under Network tab you'll see that it's not returning HTML, but XML like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet href="latest_ob.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<current_observation version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.weather.gov/view/current_observation.xsd">
  <credit>NOAA's National Weather Service</credit>
  <credit_URL>http://weather.gov/</credit_URL>
  <image>
    <url>http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</url>
    <title>NOAA's National Weather Service</title>
    <link>http://weather.gov</link>
  </image>
  <suggested_pickup>15 minutes after the hour</suggested_pickup>
  <suggested_pickup_period>60</suggested_pickup_period>
  <location>Dexter B Florence Memorial Field Airport, AR</location>
  <station_id>KM89</station_id>
  <latitude>34.1</latitude>
  <longitude>-93.07</longitude>
  <observation_time>Last Updated on Nov 23 2012, 7:56 am CST</observation_time>
        <observation_time_rfc822>Fri, 23 Nov 2012 07:56:00 -0600</observation_time_rfc822>
  <weather>Light Rain</weather>
  <temperature_string>57.0 F (13.8 C)</temperature_string>
  <temp_f>57.0</temp_f>
  <temp_c>13.8</temp_c>
  <relative_humidity>87</relative_humidity>
  <wind_string>Northeast at 8.1 MPH (7 KT)</wind_string>
  <wind_dir>Northeast</wind_dir>
  <wind_degrees>30</wind_degrees>
  <wind_mph>8.1</wind_mph>
  <wind_kt>7</wind_kt>
  <pressure_string>1027.5 mb</pressure_string>
  <pressure_mb>1027.5</pressure_mb>
  <pressure_in>30.30</pressure_in>
  <dewpoint_string>52.9 F (11.6 C)</dewpoint_string>
  <dewpoint_f>52.9</dewpoint_f>
  <dewpoint_c>11.6</dewpoint_c>
  <windchill_string>55 F (13 C)</windchill_string>
        <windchill_f>55</windchill_f>
        <windchill_c>13</windchill_c>
  <visibility_mi>10.00</visibility_mi>
  <icon_url_base>http://forecast.weather.gov/images/wtf/small/</icon_url_base>
  <two_day_history_url>http://www.weather.gov/data/obhistory/KM89.html</two_day_history_url>
  <icon_url_name>ra1.png</icon_url_name>
  <ob_url>http://www.weather.gov/data/METAR/KM89.1.txt</ob_url>
  <disclaimer_url>http://weather.gov/disclaimer.html</disclaimer_url>
  <copyright_url>http://weather.gov/disclaimer.html</copyright_url>
  <privacy_policy_url>http://weather.gov/notice.html</privacy_policy_url>
</current_observation>
```

So you can scrape it like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KM89.xml'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

p doc.at_css('station_id').text
```

Comment: You can get them by scraping this: http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/latest_ob.xsl